# Add new MySQL table columns and creating indexes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this existing query to create an additional MySQL column to an existing table.:

```
$wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN myarguments VARCHAR(255)");
```

How can I also create indexes while adding new column?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 46, accepted):

combine it adding comma, eg

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
    ADD COLUMN myarguments VARCHAR(255), 
    ADD INDEX (myarguments);
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/618c5/3)

Answer (score 0):

To create indexes, use the CREATE INDEX command:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_name);
```

To drop a non-primary key index, use the DROP INDEX command:

```
DROP INDEX index_name ON table_name;
```